# How to visualize Data in a Webapplication?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dashboard

I implemented a wireless sensor network with my own sensornodes, the famous MQTT-protocol and a Raspberry Pi. All data, which are published by the nodes, are stored in a SQLite database on the Pi. Except the database, on the RPi is a webserver located for the communication over HTTP to enddevices like smartphones or laptops. I created a HTML-form for user inputs with Bootstrap. The users can decide between different nodes, parameters and timestamps to plot charts, tables and gauges. On the server side I programmed a PHP-application which querys the user input, the database and also calls the webside. For the client side I wrote a short JavaScript file using Ajax to recieve the userinput interactiv. So far so good, now I want to viszualize the charts, gauges and tables containing the data which the PHP-application determines.
I searched a long while for dashbaords-examples and obviously I found many different, but everytime I fail with the handling of the JS sources.

My question: Can someone recommend me a lightwight and easy to handle dashboard with following characteristics?

- beginner tutorials with less JS-knowledge
- extensive presentation possibilities (Barcharts, Linecharts, gauges etc.)
- able to embed in an existing webpage
- interactive usage
- sufficient support

Maybe I'm to inexperienced with the development of webapplication and I need to get some knowledge about JS. So it would be also useful if someone recommend me  JS tutorials with jQuery.

Comment: I'd recommend https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/ as it is very easy to get started and you can add it to any site.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for! The first examples worked fine and also the tutorials are very easy to understand. Thank you very much!